# VoIP - SIP contact filed not completely empty - is RFC compliant?

Tags: parsing, sip

I'm writing some code to parse the contact field in C,and I'm encountering an empty field but instead of empty string, it is in these brackets...: "<>"(please find attached)

Is it RFC compliant? I can't find anything about it...
Thanks in advance for the answers...

[image]

Comment: So your question has nothing to do with C, has it? If so remove the useless tag, please. Otherwise please explain what your difficulty in C is.

Answer (score 1):

No it's not compliant. Below is a snippet of the Contact header parsing rules from the [SIP RFC](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3261.txt).

You can have a contact header of "Contact: *" but if the "<>" are present then it's required that they contain a properly formed SIP URI.

```
Contact        =  ("Contact" / "m" ) HCOLON
              ( STAR / (contact-param *(COMMA contact-param)))
contact-param  =  (name-addr / addr-spec) *(SEMI contact-params)
name-addr      =  [ display-name ] LAQUOT addr-spec RAQUOT
addr-spec      =  SIP-URI / SIPS-URI / absoluteURI
display-name   =  *(token LWS)/ quoted-string
```